# Pass Array HTML Element(s) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of checkboxes like below,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="a_r_id[1]" name="a_r_id[1]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="a_r_id[2]" name="a_r_id[2]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="a_r_id[3]" name="a_r_id[3]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="a_r_id[4]" name="a_r_id[4]">
```

in my page... and i want to submit only the checked one via JavaScript (jQuery AJAX)... how can i do that ?

EDITED :

Actually, i want to get all array keys on the checked checkbox so that i can post it via ajax. Something like "1,4" as a string.

Comment: Only the checked checkbox is sent in request by the browser. Are you sure you've stated your question right?

Comment: Sorry if my question is ambiguous. I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = [],
    keystring;
$('input[name^="a_r_id"]:checked').each(function () {
    keys.push($(this).attr('name').replace(/a_r_id\[(\d+)\]/, '$1'));
});
keystring = keys.join();
```

Of course, there are better ways of doing this, but this answers your question as you've framed it.

Comment: Please add explanation as to how this can be applied to answer the question.

Comment: Apologies if it isn't clear.  Obviously, only the checked values will be sent when a form is submitted, so I interpreted the question to ask how to identify the checked inputs to do something with them (such as an AJAX call). My answer will identify all inputs that begin with the name "a_r_id" which are checked, and then the developer can do something with the returned object.

Comment: @DerekHenderson, can you please explain how can i get the array keys from the returned object ? i'm a newbie on javascript. Thanks.

Comment: name is a property, so you should use .prop('name') or just this.name :)

Comment: @DerekHenderson when i try your method, it comes to an error 'undefined $1'. Why is that happen ?

Comment: @Moch.Rasyid, apologies for that. Apparently you have to wrap the backreference in quotation marks.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found an answer for my question above. I'll write it down right here.

Problem :
how can i get "key" from array HTML element(s) ? (in my case, only checked checkbox i want to get)

my answer code is something like this :

```
//first, i get every checked checkbox using jQuery selector,
//as mentioned by DerekHenderson.
var list_agent = $('input[name^="a_r_id"]:checked');
var l_c_agent = new Array();
//then, i create a loop to loop each object returned.
for(var i=0;i<list_agent.length;i++){
    //after that, i'm using Regular Expression ( match() ) on every returned object id and throw it into some array.
    l_c_agent[i] = list_agent[i].id.match(/[0-9]+/);
}
//finally, i join the array using javascript join() method so that i can pass it using jQuery AJAX as a string to my controller and process it.
var clean_agent_list = l_c_agent.join();
var add_url = 'test.php';
$.ajax({
    url: add_url,
    type: "GET",
    data : { 'list_agent' : clean_agent_list },
    success: function(data_return) {
        //alert(data_return);
    }
});
```

the output will be something like this (if using my example question above and we're check element with id 1,3 and 4 only)

```
1,3,4
```

if anybody have a better code, please write it here so that we can discuss which is better to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution.  Perhaps, since you found at least part of my answer useful, you might want to give it an upvote or even select it as the accepted answer.  ;)  (BTW, you should avoid using `new Array()`, use `[]` instead.)

Comment: @DerekHenderson how can i use [] in JavaScript ? can i just declare it as var l_c_agent[] ? and why did you suggest that rather than new Array() ? Thanks.

Comment: `var l_c_agent = [];` is better and more efficient than `var l_c_agent = new Array();`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want seems a bit backwards; the browser will already submit only the checked checkboxes, but here goes:

```
var re = /\[(\d+)\]$/,
    numbers = [];

$('input[name^="a_r_id\\["]:checked').each(function() {
    numbers.push(+this.name.match(re)[1]);
});

console.log(numbers.join(','));
```

It selects all checked boxes whose name starts with "a_r_id[". Then, a regular expression is used to extract the number portion between square brackets and added to the list of values.

Comment: i use AJAX to throw it and process it rather than use standart form submitting. I don't want user navigate away from the same page since i have another table below to show what user already choose.

Comment: your answer worked as well... you have too many }); btw... :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="a_r_id_1" name="a_r_id[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="a_r_id_2" name="a_r_id[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="a_r_id_3" name="a_r_id[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="a_r_id_4" name="a_r_id[]">
```

Answer (score -1):

Radio Buttons seems to be more applicable here rather than checkboxes try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="1" id="a_r_id[1]" name="a_r_id[1]">
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="2" id="a_r_id[2]" name="a_r_id[2]">
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="3" id="a_r_id[3]" name="a_r_id[3]">
```

You can get the selected value using

```
$("input:radio[name=radiogroup]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
//
do something with var
//
});
```

Comment: i have to use check box because i have a button to check them all. After all, the check box is generated dynamically using row data id as keys for the array. In my question above, i'm using 1,2,..,4 as example.